# Is it a problem if I place jQuery that will be used once certain HTML is injected into the DOM into the $('document').ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have a jQuery function that when a certain button is clicked it removes certain html. This HTML does not exist in the DOM until another button is clicked. The button that when clicked removes the HTML does not exist until the other button is clicked and when clicked it removes itself. Is there a problem with this being in the $('document').ready() function? If not where should it be.

Why I ask is because I know I have caused a bug somehow with this function but cannot figure out where. If you have any other ideas it would be very helpful.

Heres the code:

```
<div id="popups">
    <div id="createform">
        <div id="createformInside">
            <input type="text" id="testTitle" size="20">
            <input type="text" id="testSubj">
            <span id="testOptions">More Options</span>
            <br/>
            <textarea id="testContent" ></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Save Test" id="saveBttn">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

$('#saveBttn').click( function() {//if the save button on the create test form is clicked...
    $('#createform').remove();//gets rid of the create test form
})
```

The full code is here if this would help: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/ggJ4d/

Comment: Can you post the code for the button and how you're calling the function?  You're probably better off using the jQuery click event for the button instead of a named function, that way there aren't name collisions.

Comment: @Jim Schubert, its posted now. I used a click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the html `input` element you are binding a click handler to does not exist when the document is ready. This means it doesn't exist when your `.click()` handler is instantiated. To bind handlers to elements that exist now and in the future, you can use `.live()` or `.delegate()`. I prefer the latter, because it doesn't bind to `document` and wait for events to bubble up, instead it binds to the selector you pass it, and only watches for bubbling events that get triggered within that specific element.

So with this in mind, you can revise your code like so:

```
$('#popups').delegate("#saveBttn", "click", function() {//if the save button on the create test form is clicked...
    $('#createform').remove();//gets rid of the create test form
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use live instead of click as you are do that at runtime

Live will be used for future reference dom elements.

```
$('#saveBttn').live('click', function() {

});
```

Comment: @crhomedude , better wrap it over document.ready function...so that it will till everything loads.

Comment: doesn't seem to help. i just put the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/ggJ4d/ . Hopefully that helps.

Comment: while wrapping stuff in document.ready is a very good practice, the nature of jquery live is such that it will actually be okay to not do so in this case.  live works by event bubbling, so it doesn't matter that the relevant DOM elements are not present yet.

Comment: ahh... now I see, I wasn't completely understanding this before. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put the code in the `.click()` of the button that generates the HTML.

Btw, you need to close the `input` tags, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" id="testSubj"/>
```

instead of:

```
<input type="text" id="testSubj">
```

Based on your jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/ggJ4d/), something like this should work:

```
$('#new').click( function() {//if a new test is wanted to be created...
    $('#popups').append($formHtml);

    $('#saveBttn').click( function() {//if the save button on the create test form is clicked...
        $('#createform').empty();//gets rid of the create test form
    })
})
```

Comment: hmm... i just put the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/ggJ4d/ . Hopefully that helps.

Comment: See the edit. Note that you should check for addition - when New Test is clicked twice, you will have two forms added and they will have the same ID, which is not good. That's a separate issue, though.

Comment: ok, i see. Yeah, I knew that. That was on my list to do but it was not super important to me right now. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem, glad you found a solution!